# Symfony edit roles of User gives error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to edit the user roles from a specific user through an Symfony form.

My Form contains this:

```
 ->add('role', ChoiceType::class, [
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'choices'  => [
                  'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN',
                  'ROLE_TEST' => 'ROLE_TEST',
                  'ROLE_USER' => 'ROLE_USER'
                ],
            ]);
```

This is my method which handles the form

```
public function editUserAction(User $user, Request $request)
    {

        $userForm = $this->createForm(UserForm::class, $user);
        $userForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($userForm->isSubmitted() && $userForm->isValid()) {
            $this->userService->save($user);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('user');
        }

        return $this->render(
            'userEdit.html.twig',
            [
                'form' => $userForm->createView(),
            ]
        );
    }
```

The save method in the handler is only persisting the data to the database.

The error which I get when i try to select multiple roles is this:

> Expected argument of type
>   "Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection", "array" given

Comment: Can you post your User class? What's behind $this->userService?

Comment: Where exactly does your error appear? Post stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `by_reference` option: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#by-reference

```
->add('role', ChoiceType::class, [
            'expanded' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'choices'  => [
              'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' => 'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN',
              'ROLE_TEST' => 'ROLE_TEST',
              'ROLE_USER' => 'ROLE_USER'
            ],
           'by_reference' => false
        ]);
```

Check that you have the addRole and removeRole on the User class.